# jQuery hide doesn't hide any content in vb.net/asp.net webform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to hide my content by clicking the button. But **when the page is loading, content is hiding but after finishing page load content is showed.** This content doesn't hide. I am using Visual Studio 2017 community and asp.net/vb.net framework. But the same JQuery code is working on my text editor and my browser. 
Here is my sample code:

```
<p id="justp" class="testcls">Hi Hide me!</p>
    <asp:Button ID="testbtn" runat="server" Text="hide me" />
     <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#testbtn').click(function () {
                $('.testcls').hide();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I am try to passing alert inside hide() and it is run successfully :

```
$('.testcls').hide(alert("Hello"));
```

What is the problem? 
How can I solve this?

Comment: When you click the button it will trigger a form post (PostBack). Then all the changes made by client side code will be lost.

Comment: Thanks. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Why it's sending a form post? Is it beacuse of `<asp>` tag?

Comment: @ShiroiTora because of the `runat="server"` attribute, but simply removing that alone will probably cause other issues.

Comment: @ShiroiTora, yes and no. An `asp:Button` will generate an `input type=submit`. And a submit button will trigger a form post.

Comment: @Kaushik, if the only thing you want to do with that button is trigger some javascript then use a "normal" input control, not an ASP one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when i remove runat="server" button doesn't work. It is disappear.

Comment: As I said 'simply removing that alone will probably cause other issues'. For this to work you will most likely need to redesign how the entire form submission to the server works. You've not shown enough information here for us to help with that, and it's most likely too broad anyway

Comment: @VDWWD i am trying to `<input type="submit" ID="testbtn" Text="hide me"/>` but it also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In case your are just using this button to hide/show your content on the client side (no server side calculation or something like that) use a normal `input` / `button` tag:

**Replace this:**
`<asp:Button ID="testbtn" runat="server" Text="hide me" />`

**With this line:**
`<button type="button" id="testbtn">Hide me!</button>`

As mentioned above this solution will only work if you don't need to submit any data.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the problem?

The button submits your form after the click so the page will be refreshed and the view will return to the default status.

> How can I solve this?

You've several ways to change this behavior :

1. if you have got a control on the asp code you could remove the `runat="server"` to prevent the button from submitting :

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="testbtn" Text="hide me" />
   ```
2. You could simply add the `return false;` statement at the end of the event.
3. Another way is preventing the default behavior using `preventDefault()` like :

   ```
   $('#testbtn').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       $('.testcls').hide();
   });
   ```
4. **The one that I recommend to you is using `UseSubmitBehavior`:**

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="testbtn" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="hide me" />
   ```
5. Last choice is using the plain HTML code like :

   ```
   <button type="button" id="testbtn">Hide me!</button>
   ```

Comment: Sorry to say, I am trying to solve my problem from your answers but none of them are worked for me.

Comment: I have solved my problem with this code `<button type="button" id="testbtn">Hide me!</button>`
But your answers doesn't work for me.